# django project 3 from (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/)

Tags: django, project

[Question id not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRcxf.jpg)Hi I am following along with project number 3 on djangoprojects.com. I dropped a link in the title of the specific page I'm on so far.

As the picture titled "Question id not showing" clearly shows, the numbered questions are not showing up on the screen after I type in the url along with the question id (2) as seen below:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/2

Comment: Has anyone done that project successfully yet  ?

Comment: To improve your chances of receiving an answer, please review "How do I ask a good question" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This will help others help you quickly/more easily.

Comment: Yes, many people have completed tutorial 3 on the Django website. If the page is blank, then there's almost certainly something wrong with your code or template, but we can't help you with that because you haven't shown it.